# Sharepoint 2016 onpremise how to change central admin url domain?

Tags: 2016, site-collection, sharepoint-on-prem, url

I Installed Sharepoint 2016 on premise in a Windows Server 2016, however the installation used the machine's name to generate the url, so currently when I open my Central Administration of Sharepoint I have a very unfriendly url like:

http://win-8si9e41b3h3

And everything is using this domain, so if I access to my sites I have http://win-8si9e41b3h3/sites/projects.

How can I change it to something like:

http://mydomain.com/everything-else

Thanks and Regards!!

Comment: did you created the site collection in Central admin web application?

Comment: Yes, I have my site collection called /sites

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the central admin URL would be with below format after installing the SharePoint:

```
http://machinename:portnumber
```

Here the port number will be the one that you have given during the installation.

The MSDN article says CA port number can be changed using the below PowerShell command:

```
Set-SPCentralAdministration -Port 8282(example - you can give your own number)
```

MSDN Source:

[Set-SPCentralAdministration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spcentraladministration?view=sharepoint-ps)

You can try the above step.

And also we can change the central administration URL by other ways:

**How to change the URL for SharePoint Central Administration site**

To change the URL for SharePoint Central Administration URL:

- Open Registry editor
- Backup the registry before making any changes!!!
- Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server
  Extensions\12.0\WSS and change the value of CentralAdministrationURL
  to whatever you want to be

References:

[How to change the URL for SharePoint Central Administration site](https://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2008/11/14/How-to-change-the-URL-for-SharePoint-Central-Administration-site.aspx)

[How to change the URL for SharePoint Central Administration site](http://www.sharepointpitstop.com/2016/01/central-administration-url-change.html)

Answer (score 0):

it is recommended that you need to create a separate web application (other than CA) for regular use. CA web application is back-end work and it is only provision on 1 server and if you have multi-server environment then it will not provision on other servers ( Web front ends).

what i recommend:

1. Create DNS Alias which point to the server or Load balancer
2. Create a [Web Application in the Central admin](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/create-claims-based-web-applications) and use the DNS in it
3. Create a root level site collection
4. Update the AAM via central admin

Lastly, in your case, you have [to backup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/backup-spsite?view=sharepoint-ps) the existing Site collection and [Restore it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/restore-spsite?view=sharepoint-ps) to new web application.